# script doesnt work fully after build (Unity / C#)

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

So yesterday I finished my first game for a gamejam, I build it and uploaded it to itch.io. But when I got back to that todat I saw a message of someone who said that my player movement didnt work, while it did inside unity itself. After playing the build I also noticed that is doesnt work. But I just cant find out why not, so what are possible that make it dont work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Player_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody rb;
 
    public float X_Axis;
    public float Z_Axis;
    public float force;
 
    public bool Forward_backward;
    public bool leftward_rightward;
 
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
        Forward_backward = true;
        leftward_rightward = true;
        force = 5f;
    }
 
    public void Update()
    {
        //Sideward
        if (Input.GetKey ("a"))
        {
            if (leftward_rightward == true)
            {
                leftward_rightward = false;
                Debug.Log("leftward_rightward is false");
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            if (leftward_rightward == false)
            {
                leftward_rightward = true;
                Debug.Log("leftward_rightward is true");
            }
        }
 
        if (leftward_rightward == true)
        {
            X_Axis = force;
        }
        if (leftward_rightward == false)
        {
            X_Axis = force * -1;
        }
 
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 0f, Z_Axis));
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(X_Axis, 0f, 0f));
        }
}
```

Note: the Input of the a and d keys work, but this is switching a bool. The real movement (with w and s) doesnt work.

I tried looking in the gameLog but I couldnt find anything

Comment: in general rather try to use `GetKey(KeyCode.W)` etc does that page forward keyboard and mouse movement correctly?

Comment: a/d make it possible to move to left or right using key S, left and right make it possible to move up and down using W key. Is there a specific reason why I should use ```GetKey(KeyCode.W)``` instead of ```Input.GetKey ("w")```

Comment: I see a `public RigidBody rb;` but I don't see you setting it in start (i.e. `void Start() { rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();` ... since you're using AddForce on rb, could this be the snag?

make `rb` private and set it in Start ;-)

Comment: In the Unity editor you can drag every object with a rigidbody on it into that slot and it will use that rigidbody. I don't it's the solution because it works perfectly fine in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the force was big enough for the editor but not for the build version, increasing the force that got added to the player solved this problem.